# CakePHP 3 : upload multiple images using Proffer plugin

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-3.0, image-uploading, multiple-file-upload

I'm working on a CakePHP 3 project and using Proffer plugin for uploading images. This plugin is working fine for uploading single images.

Now I want to make it possible to upload multiple images.

I am storing images to `service_category_images` table which is related to `service_categories` with foreign key `service_category_id`.

[image: service_category_images table]

As per given in Proffer plugin guide for uploading multiple images.

**My `ServiceCategoryImagesTable.php` file has**

```
<?php
namespace App\Model\Table;

use App\Model\Entity\ServiceCategoryImage;
use Cake\ORM\Query;
use Cake\ORM\RulesChecker;
use Cake\ORM\Table;
use Cake\Validation\Validator;

/**
 * ServiceCategoryImages Model
 *
 * @property \Cake\ORM\Association\BelongsTo $ServiceCategories
 */
class ServiceCategoryImagesTable extends Table
{

    /**
     * Initialize method
     *
     * @param array $config The configuration for the Table.
     * @return void
     */
    public function initialize(array $config)
    {
        parent::initialize($config);

        $this->table('service_category_images');
        $this->displayField('id');
        $this->primaryKey('id');

        $this->addBehavior('Timestamp');
        $this->addBehavior('Proffer.Proffer', [
          'image' => [
            'root' => DS . 'var' . DS . 'www' . DS . 'html' . DS . 'flitfix' . DS . 'media' . DS . 'files',
            'dir' => 'dir'
          ]
        ]);

        $this->belongsTo('ServiceCategories', [
            'foreignKey' => 'service_category_id',
            'joinType' => 'INNER'
        ]);
    }

    public function validationDefault(Validator $validator)
    {
        $validator->provider('proffer', 'Proffer\Model\Validation\ProfferRules');

        $validator
            ->uuid('id')
            ->allowEmpty('id', 'create');

        $validator
            ->add('image', 'proffer', [
              'rule' => ['dimensions', [
                'min' => ['w' => '100', 'h' => '100'],
                'max' => ['w' => '1000', 'h' => '1000']
                ]],
                'message' => 'Please upload image of correct dimension',
                'provider' => 'proffer'
            ])
            ->requirePresence('image', 'create')
            ->allowEmpty('image');

        return $validator;
    }

    /**
     * Returns a rules checker object that will be used for validating
     * application integrity.
     *
     * @param \Cake\ORM\RulesChecker $rules The rules object to be modified.
     * @return \Cake\ORM\RulesChecker
     */
    public function buildRules(RulesChecker $rules)
    {
        $rules->add($rules->existsIn(['service_category_id'], 'ServiceCategories'));
        return $rules;
    }
}
```

**and `ServiceCategoryImage.php` entity contains**

```
<?php
namespace App\Model\Entity;

use Cake\ORM\Entity;

/**
 * ServiceCategoryImage Entity.
 *
 * @property string $id
 * @property string $service_category_id
 * @property \App\Model\Entity\ServiceCategory $service_category
 * @property string $image_01
 * @property string $image_02
 * @property string $image_03
 * @property string $image_04
 * @property string $dir
 * @property \Cake\I18n\Time $created
 * @property \Cake\I18n\Time $modified
 */
class ServiceCategoryImage extends Entity
{
    protected $_accessible = [
        '*' => true,
        'id' => false,
        'service_category_images' => true,
    ];
}
```

**`add.ctp` view of `ServiceCategoryImages` controller contains**

```
<div class="serviceCategoryImages form large-9 medium-8 columns content">
    <?= $this->Form->create($serviceCategoryImage, ['type' => 'file']) ?>
    <fieldset>
        <legend><?= __('Add Service Category Image') ?></legend>
        <?php
            echo $this->Form->input('service_category_id', ['options' => $serviceCategories]);
            echo $this->Form->input('service_category_images.0.image', ['type' => 'file']);
            echo $this->Form->input('service_category_images.1.image', ['type' => 'file']);
            echo $this->Form->input('service_category_images.2.image', ['type' => 'file']);
            echo $this->Form->input('service_category_images.3.image', ['type' => 'file']);
        ?>
    </fieldset>
    <?= $this->Form->button(__('Submit')) ?>
    <?= $this->Form->end() ?>
</div>
```

**and `ServiceCategoriesTable.php` hasMany relation as**

```
$this->hasMany('ServiceCategoryImages', [
    'foreignKey' => 'service_category_id'
]);
```

But, it is not uploading files. Is there anything wrong ?

> Edit 2 : error.log content

```
2016-06-28 06:57:30 Warning: Warning (2): getimagesize() [<a href='http://php.net/function.getimagesize'>function.getimagesize</a>]: Filename cannot be empty in [/var/www/html/flitfix/admin/vendor/davidyell/proffer/src/Model/Validation/ProfferRules.php, line 29]
Request URL: /service-category-images/add
Referer URL: http://admin.flitfix2.com/service-category-images/add
Client IP: 127.0.0.1
Trace:
Cake\Error\BaseErrorHandler::handleError() - CORE/src/Error/BaseErrorHandler.php, line 146
getimagesize - [internal], line ??
Proffer\Model\Validation\ProfferRules::dimensions() - ROOT/vendor/davidyell/proffer/src/Model/Validation/ProfferRules.php, line 29
Cake\Validation\ValidationRule::process() - CORE/src/Validation/ValidationRule.php, line 138
Cake\Validation\Validator::_processRules() - CORE/src/Validation/Validator.php, line 1505
Cake\Validation\Validator::errors() - CORE/src/Validation/Validator.php, line 137
Cake\ORM\Marshaller::_validate() - CORE/src/ORM/Marshaller.php, line 203
Cake\ORM\Marshaller::merge() - CORE/src/ORM/Marshaller.php, line 488
Cake\ORM\Table::patchEntity() - CORE/src/ORM/Table.php, line 2099
App\Controller\ServiceCategoryImagesController::add() - APP/Controller/ServiceCategoryImagesController.php, line 56
Cake\Controller\Controller::invokeAction() - CORE/src/Controller/Controller.php, line 429
Cake\Routing\Dispatcher::_invoke() - CORE/src/Routing/Dispatcher.php, line 114
Cake\Routing\Dispatcher::dispatch() - CORE/src/Routing/Dispatcher.php, line 87
[main] - ROOT/webroot/index.php, line 36
```

**debug.log content**

```
2016-06-28 06:57:30 Notice: Notice (8): Undefined index: tmp_name in [/var/www/html/flitfix/admin/vendor/davidyell/proffer/src/Model/Validation/ProfferRules.php, line 29]
Request URL: /service-category-images/add
Referer URL: http://admin.flitfix2.com/service-category-images/add
Client IP: 127.0.0.1
Trace:
Cake\Error\BaseErrorHandler::handleError() - CORE/src/Error/BaseErrorHandler.php, line 146
Proffer\Model\Validation\ProfferRules::dimensions() - ROOT/vendor/davidyell/proffer/src/Model/Validation/ProfferRules.php, line 29
Cake\Validation\ValidationRule::process() - CORE/src/Validation/ValidationRule.php, line 138
Cake\Validation\Validator::_processRules() - CORE/src/Validation/Validator.php, line 1505
Cake\Validation\Validator::errors() - CORE/src/Validation/Validator.php, line 137
Cake\ORM\Marshaller::_validate() - CORE/src/ORM/Marshaller.php, line 203
Cake\ORM\Marshaller::merge() - CORE/src/ORM/Marshaller.php, line 488
Cake\ORM\Table::patchEntity() - CORE/src/ORM/Table.php, line 2099
App\Controller\ServiceCategoryImagesController::add() - APP/Controller/ServiceCategoryImagesController.php, line 56
Cake\Controller\Controller::invokeAction() - CORE/src/Controller/Controller.php, line 429
Cake\Routing\Dispatcher::_invoke() - CORE/src/Routing/Dispatcher.php, line 114
Cake\Routing\Dispatcher::dispatch() - CORE/src/Routing/Dispatcher.php, line 87
[main] - ROOT/webroot/index.php, line 36
```

Comment: Is there an error message or log entry?

Comment: Added log file generated in `error.log` and `debug.log`

Comment: From the logs it looks like the problem is in the Proffer plugin. Either you missed some sort of configuration for multiple uploads or you need to do some more debugging starting on why `tmp_name` index is missing in `ProfferRules.php`, line 29.